# Giphy Dashboard data using api

Tags: python, giphy, giphy-api

I am trying to get GIPHY Dashboard data like :

Total GIF/ stickers Upload
GIF views

When I download/Export the data , the endpoint is:
https://giphy.com/api/v2/users/aggregations/?start_dt=2013-02-01&end_dt=2020-07-08&content_type=gif,sticker

I need to get the same data via API . I also read documentation but not able to find.The documentation only has V1 api whereas above link / endpoint is V2[image]

I am using Python.
Could anyone please help me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
https://giphy.com/api/v2/users/aggregations/?start_dt=2013-02-01&end_dt=2020-07-08&content_type=gif,sticker&api_key={api_token}
```

Have you tried to reach this endpoint? Can you enter your api_token here and try it?

```
import requests
url = '...'
response = requests.get(url)
response.json()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this before but unfortunately its not working